# Django Extend Model with Optional Fields

Tags: python, django

I have a django model that looks something like

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    favorite_color = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    favorite_candy = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and I want to make a template model for it. Basically, I want a model that can have an arbitrary amount of `Person`'s fields filled out. For instance, say I wanted to have a template for `Person` that likes chocolate - I'd say something like `chocolate_template = PersonTemplate(favorite_color='chocolate')` and if I wanted someone whose name is Gerald, I could say `gerald_template = PersonTemplate(name='Gerald')`. The thought is that I could use these template objects to later pre-fill a `Person` creation form.

My main question is an implementation question. It's totally possible for me to make a template like so

```
class PersonTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    favorite_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    favorite_candy = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

but the code is horrible in that I have to manually copy-paste the contents of the `Person` class. This means that if I change `Person`, I have to remember to update `PersonTemplate`. I was wondering if there's a prettier way to make a 'child' of a model where all of the fields are optional. Setting all of the fields of `Person` to `blank=True` and adding an `isTemplate` field is also a no-no because `Person` and `PersonTemplate` should be two different entities in the database. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course :)

```
class PersonTemplate(Person):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Its mean you have every fields from Person and you can add more specific fields for PersonTemplate

```
class Person(models.Model):
```

Already extend from Model, its why you have access to `created`, `modified`, `id`, `pk`....

What is good its PersonTemplate 'extend' Person who 'extend' Model.

Since Django 1.10 you can overrride field like that :

```
class PersonTemplate(Person):
    favorite_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    favorite_candy = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Comment: I might've asked my question too ambiguously, but I think this solution would be problematic. For instance, say the `Person` model mandates that all fields are required. Let's say that I want a template of a `Person` where only `name` is set, and the other fields are blank. If I extend `Person`, then I could not instantiate `PersonTemplate` because the remaining required fields, `favorite_color` and `favorite_candy`, are blank yet required.

Comment: I'm aware of that solution (see my question), I was wondering if there was any way to make a cleaner solution? It's easy enough to do that, but then you have to copy paste a bunch of code, which means that when you edit the `Person` model, you have to go back and edit the `PersonTemplate` model too. I was wondering if there was a way to avoid hard-coding `PersonTemplate`.

Comment: Its not the same code, my exemple extend from `Person`, and i juste override `favorite_color` and  `favorite_candy` to add `blank=True`. So you can add what you want to `PersonTemplate ` it will not change for `Person`, but you can add field to `Person` and they will be availible to `PersonTemplate` without you re-declaring them. In my exemple i have a `name` field in `PersonTemplate`

Comment: But the premise of `PersonTemplate` is that all fields are optional in the first place, so if you were to add a required field to `Person`, you'd still need to add it to `PersonTemplate`. While I agree that extending `Person` is a smart move, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve copy/pasting the contents of the `Person` class into the `PersonTemplate` class

Comment: i think your problem is a coding paradigm :) Normaly when you extend from a Class (Person), this class is Standardized, mean everything here need to be the same for every class who extend (PersonTemplate). What you want is Person extend from PersonTemplate :) and this will work for you

Comment: I get that but either way I extend it, I'll still have to copy/paste a lot. What I'm going to try and do is have a boolean `is_template` tag and then override `PersonTemplate`'s `clean` method based on whether or not `is_template` is true or not